# I need Q_EMIT example

Tags: c++, qt

Now I'm learning QT ,but I don't understand  Q_EMIT on internet,I didn't found a specific syntax or relevant example. pls help me!

I found just this: 
Use this macro to replace the emit keyword for emitting signals, when you want to use Qt Signals and Slots with a 3rd party signal/slot mechanism.

The macro is normally used when no_keywords is specified with the CONFIG variable in the .pro file, but it can be used even when no_keywords is not specified.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you describe your issue in more detail, please? E.g. by adding code, commands or screen shots which describe your problem. Please have also a look to the Help Center, especially for [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Qt system is based on the concept of "signals" and "slots". A "signal" is something that happens, typically user input, and a "slot" is simply code. You can connect signals to slots, such that the slot is invoked whenever the signal is triggered.
Implementation-wise, both signals and slots are C++ methods, where the code for the signal will call out to all the slots (and signals) connected to it.
You can read more about signals and slots in [the Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html).

Knowing that, the `Q_EMIT` and `emit` macros are indicators meant for humans reading the code, namely that you are invoking a signal (which, as I explained above, implicitly calls out to all slots connected to it). Thus, this method call might have consequences elsewhere in the system. The macros themselves expand to empty C++ code.
If you have a signal `connected()` somewhere in your object, you can call it either as `Q_EMIT connected();` or `emit connected();` or even `connected();`

Comment: Small nitpick: Both signals and slots are "simply code": they are plain old C++ methods, except the slot's implementation is written by the user, and the signal's implementation is written by the `moc` tool. That generated implementation iterates the connection list and activates anything connected to a given signal.

Answer (score 0):

`Q_EMIT` is simply a synonym for `emit`.

This is useful when you're combining Qt code with other C++ code that also contains the identifier `emit`.